# how to disable auto layout by default for xcode 4.5?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5

A question here: [Xcode 4.5 corrupting XIBs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11137669/xcode-4-5-corrupting-xibs) illustrates the problem and solution for xcode 4.5 creating nib files that can not run on ios5.

Does anyone have a solution to prevent the auto layout checkbox from being defaulted to on? I'm worried that in the process of development, I will forget to unchecked that box.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's a way, but it's kinda convoluted and, I might add, not recommended.

You can open your template files located in:

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/User Interface/`, in each directory, there are .xib files. They are XML files, open them with a text editor.

Replace the following line:

```
<bool key="IBDocument.UseAutolayout">YES</bool>
```

to

```
<bool key="IBDocument.UseAutolayout">NO</bool>
```

I will repeat though, **this is not recommended**.

Comment: That is interesting. Is it not recommended because it will get overridden during upgrades? Or because it will not get overridden during upgrades? Or some other reason?

Comment: Since autolayouts crashes on apps running under iOS 5.0 (which I have to support) it is worth it to me to do this.  Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

There is a project templates folder, you should modify the xib files there too.

Also if you want to disable auto layout in storyboards, you should change this attribute:

```
useAutolayout="YES"
```

in each storyboard file to NO.